# I am trying to write data into file

Tags: python, file, save

When I run then i get error.why print man gave error and also os.getwd() also give error.But when i comment that then there is no error.code works according to expectation

```
from __future__ import print_function;
    import os
    man=[]
    other = []
    print os.getcwd()
    try:
        data = open("sketch.txt")
        for each_line in data:
            try:
                (role,line_spoken) = each_line.split(':',1)
                line_spoken = line_spoken.strip()
                if role=='Man':
                    man.append(line_spoken)
                elif role =='Other Man':
                    other.append(line_spoken)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        data.close()
    except IOError:
        print ("The Data File is Missing")
    print man
    print other
    try:
        man_file = open('man_data.txt','w')
        other_file = open('other_data.txt','w')
        print (man,file = man_file)
        print (other,file = other_file)
        other_file.close()
        man_file.close()
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `print` as function, because you import `print_function`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("Hello World")
```

Comment: I am new to python so please explain if i comment last try section then it is working fine..And if i want to print whether data is in list or not.How will i do.

Comment: In python2 `print` is statement and called without brackets, but in python3 it became a function and need brackets. Module `__future__` is used for compatibility.

Comment: Thank You.. @Eugene Soldatov

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see the following.
1) In the first line there is a ';' that could be removed.
2) the second line 'import...' and the rest to the bottom have tabs that should be removed. These lines should be in the same col that line 1 ('from ...')
3) when you use 'print' (as other people are saying) you should use '(' & ')'.
4) for coherence you should get used to follow the same approach in all your code (good practiceS), if there are no spaces between function names and parameters (i.e. line 7: data = open("sketch...) then go on with them. The same for strings, the code compile, but it is better if you use ' or " not mix them along the code.

looking forward to help!